# Why this javascript code gives error

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, jquery, javascript-framework

It gives the following error

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

My code is

```
  __doPostBack('<%= btnExitChatRoom.ClientID %>', '');
```

Comment: Where is your Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

The error does not come from that Javascript code *per se*. The code behind your page is trying to add or remove controls from a container that includes code blocks (`<%= btnExitChatRoom.ClientID %>` in your case), and ASP.NET cannot do that.

You can work around this problem by using a [data binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx):

```
__doPostBack('<%# btnExitChatRoom.ClientID %>', '');
```

Then explicitly calling the [DataBind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) method of the container from your code-behind.

Comment: I want to call btnExitChatRoom click Event every 4 second but it's not happening using your code

Comment: @Mangal, that's strange. It should, unless you forgot to call `DataBind()` from the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to databind then take this code out of the header and put it just before the  element closes